# Collection of collection of integer

Tags: excel, vba, collections

I'm generating casual groups of gcard people indexed by number from 1 to pmax

The problem is that collection "persone" is allways the same ...
gruppi(i) reference the same "persone" for every "i"

I want a new collection inside every "gruppi(i)"
How can i do that ?

```
Dim gruppi As New Collection
Dim persone As New Collection


gmax = -Int(-(pmax / gcard))

conta = 1

For g = 1 To gmax

    gruppi.Add persone

    'ciclo sulle persone del gruppo
    For p = 1 To gcard

        cas = Round(Rnd() * (pmax - 1) + 1, 0)

riprova:

        'check if cas was generated before
        For i = 1 To gruppi.Count

            For j = 1 To gruppi(i).Count
                If gruppi(i)(j) = cas Then
                    cas = Round(Rnd() * (pmax - 1) + 1, 0)
                    GoTo riprova
                End If
            Next

        Next

continua:

        'person "cas" not present, ok let's add it!
        gruppi(g).Add cas

        'MsgBox "gruppi -> " & gruppi.Count
        'MsgBox "persone nel gruppo " & g & " -> " & gruppi(g).Count

        conta = conta + 1
        If conta > pmax Then GoTo esci

    Next p

Next g

esci:
```

Comment: It would help if you declared all your variables (or shared them in the code supplied).Can you show expected output using some sample data?

Comment: You are creating a collection of collections just there is nothing added inside the collections unless that is coming from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's because with

```
Dim gruppi As New Collection
Dim persone As New Collection 

For g = 1 To gmax
    gruppi.Add persone
    ....
```

you keep referencing the same `persone` object for every `gruppi` item you may add...

then you want to use:

```
Dim gruppi As New Collection

For g = 1 To gmax
    gruppi.Add New Collection ' add a new collection as the new item of 'gruppi' collection
    ....
```

which, by the way, allows for an object variable less to declare and use

and since it's best practice to declare and instantiate